# How to get the charge Id after subscribing a customer to a plan with recurring payment?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have successfully created a customer in stripe with a subscription of plan .After successful payment I am not able to get the charge Id because after subscribing a customer to a plan.It automatically generates an invoice.So what is the way that I can get that particular charge stripe Id from stripe and store it in my system database.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the charge ID for a subscription (or an invoice) can be done via [their webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) integration. You need to expose an API in your app where Stripe can fire these requests. You can subscribe to various events there, but in your case you'd need to do so on `charge.succeeded`. The charge ID will be in the [data](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object#event_object-data) structure of the event object.

Take a look at the various [other lifecycle events](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events) you can use with webhooks.

Comment: As you said I integrated a webhook.But I receive every single event (i.e customer created,subscribtion created,invoice generated) but I want only charge related events.How can i get those events ?

Comment: yes, that's correct stripe will send you all events. You can filter these events by the event type, and discard the rest if they are not relevant to your needs.

Comment: what should be the type I need to set for getting the chargeId?

Comment: @PoonamKaria it's `charge.succeeded`. It's mentioned in my answer as well.

Comment: I'll show you my code when I debug it .It doesn't show me the list with type charge.succeeded.  var service = new EventService();
            var options = new EventListOptions
            {
              Type = "charge.succeeded",
              Limit = 3,

            };
            StripeList<Event> events = service.List(options);

Comment: That will be a different issue if you can't see that specific event type. The type definitely exists and used widely.

Comment: there in I get the list of all the customers with their charge Id but I want only a particular customer's charge Id