# How to get the Charge ID after subscribing a customer to a plan in .net core 2.0 using Stripe API

Tags: model-view-controller, stripe-payments, .net-core-2.0

I have created a customer then subscribed it to a plan.Now I need to know whether the payment done by the customer succeeded or failed.So how to get that stripe response in .net core 2.0.I need to create a webhook. How to retrieve the webhook notification for every event occurred before

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the charge Id after subscribing a customer to a plan with recurring payment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54476932/how-to-get-the-charge-id-after-subscribing-a-customer-to-a-plan-with-recurring-p)

Comment: @Mate I am still not getting that chargeId in my webhook.Could you please help me with it